# Server Not Found in Kerberos database - where is the database located?

Tags: active-directory, redhat, kerberos, mitkerberos

Testing setup:

- Weblogic 12.2.1.4 running on a Windows 10 machine joined to an active directory

  - JVM 1.8.0_281
  - The java web application is using Java GSSAPI to access the fileshare over Samba essentially using the code from https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/issues/304#issuecomment-375603115
  - This is a developer machine - the java system property "user.name" shows the developer's windows username
- Linux fileserver running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, configured with sssd to connect to Active Directory
- Linux fileserver running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, *not* using sssd, *not* using winbind (unclear how precisely it is configured for Active Directory)

From what I've been able to gather third-hand on conversations with sysadmins, MIT Kerberos is somehow involved in connecting the linux servers to Active Directory - but I have no more information on that.

(note: serverfault is having markdown table rendering issue - table displays fine in preview, but not in actual posted question, so surrounded in code block for now so that it doesn't all run together)

Test Results

```
| Source (all on same Windows 10 machine)  | Target FileServer     | Result  |
|------------------------------------------|-----------------------|---------|
| Weblogic application                     | RHEL 6                | Success |
| Weblogic application                     | RHEL 7                | **Fail:** Server not found in Kerberos database |
| Windows Explorer                         | RHEL 6                | Success |
| Windows Explorer                         | RHEL 7                | Success |
```

All tests done using the same user credentials.

The trace results from Weblogic (after setting the java system property `sun.security.krb5.debug` to `true`) are:

```
KrbAsReqBuild: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=***************. UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=233
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=***************. UDP: 88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=233
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=100
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=*****************. TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retires =3, #bytes=233
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=****************. TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=233
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 2695 bytes
>>>KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=2695
>>>KdcAccessibility: remove **********************.:88
>>>Etype: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>>KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply ******
Found ticket for ******@******** to go to krbtgt/******@****** expiring on ******
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Found ticket for ******@******** to go to krbtgt/******@****** expiring on ******
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 16 23
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.HmacSha1Aes256CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=************. TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=2633
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=************. TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=2633
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 104 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=104
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove *************.:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
>>>KRBError:
        STime is **********
        suSec is **********
        error code is 7
        error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
        sname is cifs/***********@***********
        msgType is 30
```

Searching for "Server not found in Kerberos database" yields a number of possibilities (DNS seems to be most common suggestion, other answers have suggested SPN registrations, TLS certs, not using FQDN, invalid host to realm mapping, host not part of domain, IPV4 vs IPV6)

The network admins say DNS is correct, which would appear to be substantiated by the fact that Windows explorer can connect to the RHEL 7 server just fine.  But neither am I prepared to just blame the java code, since it *does* successfully connect to the RHEL 6 server.

I'm having difficulty finding a clear explanation of what Kerberos entries need to be configured where.

Is this "Kerberos database" on the Windows 10 machine, the fileserver, or the Active Directory KDC?  Or are there multiple copies of this Kerberos database that each need entries?

**Edit - Additional Details**
I've learned a few new things and can provide some additional details.

The following are all from a Window's command prompt on the Developer machine.

Realm is determined by:

```
C:\>echo %userdnsdomain%
DC1.DC2.DC3
```

For the successful connection (RHEL 6 server)

```
C:\>powershell Get-ADComputer server1

DistinguishedName : CN=SERVER1,OU=ou1,OU=ou2,OU=ou3,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3
DNSHostName       : server1.dc2.dc3
Enabled           : True
Name              : SERVER1
ObjectClass       : Computer
ObjectGUID        : aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
SamAccountName    : server1$
SID               : ************************************
UserPrincipalName :

C:\>setspn -L server1
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER1,OU=ou1,OU=ou2,OU=ou3,DC=dc1,DC=dc2, DC=dc3:
        HOST/server1.dc2.dc3
        HOST/SERVER1

C:\>nslookup server1
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.7.890

C:\>nslookup 123.456.7.890
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.7.890
```

For the failing connection (RHEL 7 server)

```
C:\>powershell Get-ADComputer server2

DistinguishedName : CN=SERVER2,OU=ou4,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3
DNSHostName       : server2.dc1.dc2.dc3
Enabled           : True
Name              : SERVER2
ObjectClass       : Computer
ObjectGUID        : bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb
SamAccountName    : SERVER2$
SID               : ************************************
UserPrincipalName :

C:\>setspn -L server2
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER2,OU=ou4,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3:
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2
        HOST/SERVER2
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2.dc1.dc2.dc3
        HOST/SERVER2.dc1.dc2.dc3

C:\>nslookup server2
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server2.dc1.dc2.dc3
Address:  12.345.6.78

C:\>nslookup 12.345.6.78
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server2.dc2.dc3
Address:  12.345.6.78
```

Comparing the Weblogic trace results for the success vs failure:

success:

```
>>> DEBUG: ----Credentials----
        client: username@DC1.DC2.DC3
        server: cifs/server1.dc2.dc3@DC1.DC2.DC3
        ticket: sname: cifs/server1.dc2.dc3@DC1.DC2.DC3
```

failure:

```
>>>KRBError:
  ...
         error code is 7
         error Message is is Server not found in Kerberos database
         sname is cifs/server2.dc2.dc3@DC1.DC2.DC3
         msgType is 30
```

So I note a few things:

- The successful (RHEL 6) server omits "dc1" in a number of places (but not all)
- The successful and failing `sname` differ only in the server portion - they otherwise line up on the "dc" values.
- The two servers are in different Organizational Units (though I don't think this is the issue)
- There are a few difference in capitalization in the command results
- There appears to be a difference in the `nslookup` results for `server2` depending on whether it is looked up by server name (includes `dc1`) or ip address (excludes `dc1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working.

## The critical pieces

- Reverse DNS must match Forward DNS
- The SPN (Service Principal Name) must be explicitly added in some cases - merely  joining to the Active Directory Domain will not always register all the necessary `HOST` SPNs.
- In some cases, it may additionally be necessary to explicitly associate a server with a realm in the `krb5.conf` file.  This appears to be applicable when you have multiple Kerberos realms involved. **Note:** you must restart WebLogic or reboot the server for changes to `krb5.conf` to take effect.

## Summary

- I believe it is the case that the "Kerberos Database" lives with the "Key Distribution Center", which for Windows is Active Directory.
- Forward and Reverse dns entries (as demonstrated e.g. by `nslookup` in  Windows) must match.

  - I believe the reverse DNS lookup will be used to get a servername which will then be used to query the KDC for the purposes of validating the server.
- There must be a two-way trust relationship between the linux server (maybe MIT Kerberos?) and the Active Directory.  On the linux side, this is established with a keytab.
- The server portion of the Service Principal Name (SPN) may in some cases *not* match the DNS name reported by `nslookup`

  - <strike>This can still work *if* the SPN is added with the proper credentials.</strike> (edit - after further review, this was not indicated in our environment - I got mixed up on which setting was the original)
  - There should be an SPN (for samba, that would be a `HOST` spn) that coincides with the name reported by `nslookup`. In most cases, the correct HOST SPNs should be automatically added when the machine is joined to the domain, but in some cases it may be necessary to be explicitly add the SPN with e.g. `setspn -A`
  - If the server portion of the SPN cannot be resolved by DNS, that SPN will not be usable.
- `DNSHostName` as reported by `powershell Get-ADComputer` does *not* appear to be important for getting things to work. (Note this can be different from the results reported by `nslookup`)
- Service Principals can show up on Windows side or linux side - and they are not necessarily mirror images.

  - For example, on linux side we would see a `cifs/server2.dc2.dc3@DC1.DC2.DC3` in the samba logs, but from Windows neither `setspn -L server1` nor `setspn -L server2` ever showed that SPN.

## The process that fixed the issue:

1. We removed the linux server from Active Directory
2. We modified the dns entries so that using `nslookup` by name or ip returned the same results
3. We recreated the keytab in linux

   - This allowed linux to trust Active Directory, but not vice versa
4. We rejoined the linux server to Active Directory

   - at this stage, we still could *not* connect in java, but we could connect in Windows Explorer
   - at this stage `setspn -L server2` contained the SPN `HOST/server2.dc1.dc2.dc3` but did **not** have the SPN `HOST/server2.dc2.dc3`
5. We added the SPN using `setspn` from a Windows command prompt.

   - This requires domain admin or delegated permissions (I think for the machine principal)
   - `setspn -A HOST/server2.dc2.dc3 server2$`
   - The above command creates a new service principal using the machine account credentials

## Uncertainties

Still not entirely clear why Windows Explorer always worked, but I do note that Java has its own portion of Kerberos implementation - so that may play role in the requirement for the additional SPN to be explicitly registered.

It is a bit interesting that we actually found that there were two different Kerberos Realms involved.

1. `DC1.DC2.DC3` as determined from the Windows command `echo %userdnsdomain%`
2. `ccc.dc2.dc3` as determined form the linux `krb5.conf`

However, once we added the final SPN, we could connect using either Kerberos Realm (case-sensitive).

## Final Configuration

The final configuration that worked was as follows.  Some of the spns are probably unnecessary (e.g I don't think the `RestrictedKrbHost` spns are necessary, because `server1` doesn't have them), and I'm pretty sure that `DNSHostName` as determent by `Get-ADComputer` is irrelevant to this issue (as it did not change form the non-working and working configurations.)

```
C:\> echo %userdnsdomain%
DC1.DC2.DC3

C:\> powershell Get-ADComputer server2
DistinguishedName : CN=SERVER2,OU=ou4,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3
DNSHostName       : server2.dc1.dc2.dc3
Enabled           : True
Name              : SERVER2
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb
SamAccountName    : SERVER2$
SID               : ************************************
UserPrincipalName :

C:\>setspn -L server2
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER2,OU=ou4,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=dc3:
        HOST/server2.dc2.dc3
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2
        HOST/SERVER2
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2.dc1.dc2.dc3
        HOST/SERVER2.dc1.dc2.dc3

C:\>nslookup server2
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server2.dc2.dc3
Address:  12.345.6.78

C:\>nslookup 12.345.6.78
Server:  aa1.dc2.dc3
Address:  123.456.789.01

Name:    server2.dc2.dc3
Address:  12.345.6.78
```

In our case, when we later deployed the application to WebLogic running on RHEL7:

- we again got "Server not found in Kerberos database" when we specified the user in the "linux" realm `ccc.dc2.dc3` running MIT Kerberos
- we got "No Service Creds" when we specified the user in the "Active Directory" realm `DC1.DC2.DC3`.

  - The solution was to modify `/etc/krb5.conf` on the linux weblogic server to explicitly associate the fileserver with the Active Directory realm, e.g.:

  ```
  [domain_realm]
  server2.dc2.dc3 = DC1.DC2.DC3
  ```

Comment: appreciate the detailed answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the culprit:

```
    error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
    sname is cifs/***********@***********
```

The first question to ask is if the failing server has appropriate computer account in AD (and the fact it has sssd configured doesn't necessarily imply that depending on HOW sssd is configured).

Assuming this is present you may use `setspn` Windows command or OpenLDAP `ldapsearch` command to check if that computer object has appropriate service principals present. If I remeber correctly HOST/* SPN should suffice but if not (please check Microsoft documentation on that topic) cifs/ SPN may be necessary. `setspn` command can be used to create them (given appropriate privileges of the user trying to do that).

The next step is to make sure samba configuration on the Linux server has keytab created and accessible and making sure the above-mentioned cifs/* principal is present there.

I am not AD expert (just attaching some Linux systems there) so this may not be complete list but hopefully - it gives you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the server with AD?  As in - you see it in AD Users & Computers?  The message might be referring to your system not being found/registered.  Sometimes this is because the DNS name for the server differs from the AD domain name.

Another thing to keep an eye on is the clock.  If the clocks are to far out of sync lots of things break with kerberos.

Comment: I don't think have permissions to see that level of information - however, since Windows explorer _does_ connect to the server, wouldn't that indicate that the server is registered in the AD?

Comment: Looked into available powershell modules, and using `Get-ADComputer` I can see that both the RHEL 6 and RHEL 7 servers return information.  But I notice that the DNSHostName for the RHEL 7 server has an extra component.  So I'm going to try to followup on your hint about the DNS name differing from the AD domain name.